ODOO Concurrent update cuase odoo.service.model: SERIALIZATION_FAILURE,
We have problems in ODOO when updating a model concurrently.
2024-05-18 15:07:34,315 28071 INFO odoo17 odoo.service.model: SERIALIZATION_FAILURE, 4 tries left, try again in 1.1188 sec... 
2024-05-18 15:07:34,330 28073 INFO odoo17 werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/May/2024 15:07:34] "POST /jsonrpc HTTP/1.1" 200 - 9 0.058 0.098
2024-05-18 15:07:34,464 28075 ERROR odoo17 odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "stock_location" SET "write_date" = '2024-05-18 15:07:29.807524', "write_uid" = 2 WHERE id IN (26)
ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update

Even though we do not have a single update for stock.location, the stock.quant model is being updated while we update stock.location.
odoo.service.model: SERIALIZATION_FAILURE.  THIS SLOW DOWN ODOO.

Note: We are updating and deleting stock quants 200,000
